# How to dynamically get the country code based on selected country

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, country-codes

Here is the piece of code that i am using. I have to show the country code automatically based on selected country by the user.

I have a database which has both, the countries and corresponding country code.

Now in the line where currently I am showing **+91**
 how can i put the logic to do the same ?

Here is the code --

```
<div class="phone-number-verify-widget">
  <p class="pnaw-verification-error"></p>
  <div class="pnaw-step1">
    <div class="phone-number-input-widget" id="phone-number-input-widget-d04854e1">
  <label for="phone_country">Choose a country:</label>
  <div class="select">
    <select id="phone_country" name="phone_country">
        <option value="AF" data-prefix="93">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="AD" data-prefix="376">....
        <option value="ZW" data-prefix="263">Zimbabwe</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <label for="phone_number">Add a phone number:</label>
  <div class="pniw-number-container clearfix">
    **<div class="pniw-number-prefix">+91</div>**
    <input type="text" class="pniw-number" id="phone_number">
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" data-role="phone_number" name="phone" value="91">
  <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="19935817">
</div>
```

Kindly guide.

Comment: Use AJAX.

1)When selecting a country, Value say for Ahganisthan AF will get.
2)Select the corresponding code from the database.

Comment: If you do not know PHP (guessing), you can use JavaScript to load in the relevant country if you have your db converted to a JS object.

Comment: @KohjahBreese I know PHP more then what i know in JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1)        <script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    //--------------------------------------------------download jquery 
        <div class="phone-number-verify-widget">
          <p class="pnaw-verification-error"></p>
          <div class="pnaw-step1">
            <div class="phone-number-input-widget" id="phone-number-input-widget-d04854e1">
          <label for="phone_country">Choose a country:</label>
          <div class="select">
            <select id="phone_country" name="phone_country">
                <option value="AF" data-prefix="93">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="AD" data-prefix="376">....
                <option value="ZW" data-prefix="263">Zimbabwe</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <label for="phone_number">Add a phone number:</label>
          <div class="pniw-number-container clearfix">
            **<div class="pniw-number-prefix">+91</div>**
            <input type="text" class="pniw-number" id="phone_number">
          </div>
          <input type="hidden" data-role="phone_number" name="phone" value="91">
          <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="19935817">
        </div>
        <script>
            $('#phone_country').change(function(){
                var country = $('#phone_country').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "result.php",//place your url of php file
                    type: "Post",
                    data: {country : country},// this post value used to match the data from database
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('.pniw-number-prefix').html(data);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                        alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                        alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>

2) Result.php file as i used in my code
<?php
$cc = $_POST['country'];
//using the $cc feth the code from database
// your query...............
// just to show the value i have assuming $isd value as 41
$isd = '41';    
echo $isd;
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Here you have used POST to get the country selected .. but this can't be done until and unless user dont click the submit button.. and here in between submit button cant be used.

So how do I handle this ?

Comment: this is on ajax and the call works on change of dropdown value as you select other value. Try it

Comment: yes .. I realized.. Was a stupid question

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know your codebase I roughly describe what I would do:

1. Get jQuery
2. Write an event listener on the change event of #phone_country
3. do an ajax call to a simple phpscript which queries the database providing me data i want
4. Update the field with the retrieved data

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of countries or fetch from your database if you have a countries master.
You will get a result of countries in a array.
Then make your country selection dynamic.

Comment: I do have countries master in my database which has both country name and code. I am not understanding how to get do is. I know hot fetch the values of country and code from the DB but thn I get stuck with html

Comment: Post your array of countries then i will see how can i help.

Comment: array looks like - [array](http://pastebin.com/iK59HPSC)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $countries = array(array('Country'=>'India','CountryCode'=>'IN'),array('Country'=>'US','CountryCode'=>'US'),array('Country'=>'United Kingdom','CountryCode'=>'UK'));
    $selcountry = 'US';
    if(count($countries) > 0)
    {
        for($i=0;$i<count($countries);$i++)
        {
            $longname[$i] = $countries[$i]['Country'];
            $shortname[$i] = $countries[$i]['CountryCode'];
        }
    }
    $countrycombo = '';
    $countrycombo = '<select>';
    for($i=0;$i<count($shortname);$i++) 
    {
        if (trim($selcountry)==trim($shortname[$i])) 
        {
            $countrycombo .= "<option value='".$shortname[$i]."' selected>".$longname[$i]." (".$shortname[$i].") </option>";
        } 
        else 
        {
            $countrycombo .= "<option value='".$shortname[$i]."'>".$longname[$i]." (".$shortname[$i].") </option>";
        }
    }
    $countrycombo .= '</select>';
    echo $countrycombo;
?>
```

Comment: You can ask me for help :)

Comment: I guess you didnt understand my question

I have a dropdwon of country .. Now when user, say, selects INDIA then in the phone number 91 should come automatically.

Comment: Then you need a field in your database to reffer the code.

Comment: i do have the code field

Comment: Then you have to make a ajax call on change of dropdown, passing the selected value of country dropdown you can retrieve the isd code and show at the place of +91